# Brightcove: Adding preroll and postroll ads

Tags: brightcove

I am trying to implement preroll AND postroll adverts via the Brightcove player.

There are 1000's of videos, so it's not as simple as adding cue points to the media - need to aplly this to all videos.

The documentation is not helping much.

Anyone now how i can do this?

I can also achieve this by calling an ad at 0 seconds (preroll) and the total duration of the video minus 1 second (postroll)

I have the a valid ad server URL which works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server URL, you will need access to the Brightcove Players Module. The 'Advertising' section lets you enter the Server URL, as well as specify when Ads are displayed, the technology (Html5 or Flash preferred) and other options.
All videos shown through that player should then display your ads (unless the specific videos have been set to not show ads).